# How to use PostgreSQL INSERT ON CONFLICT statement

Tags: postgresql, conflict

I try to add or update postgresql, after referring to some articles I get the following statement

I read this [article](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/).

I have three tables.

users

```
id auto increase PK
Name
```

articles

```
id auto increase PK
author_id FK Reference users
```

notes

```
id auto increase PK
author_id FK Reference users
article_id FK Reference articles
```

First

```
INSERT INTO notes (author_id, article_id)
VALUES(1,1) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT author_id 
DO NOTHING;
```

get ERROR:  constraint "author_id" for table "notes" does not exist

Second

```
INSERT INTO notes (author_id, article_id)
VALUES(1,1) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT author_id REFERENCES 'users'
DO NOTHING;
```

get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REFERENCES"

Third

```
INSERT INTO notes (author_id, article_id)
VALUES(1,1) 
ON CONFLICT (author_id)
DO NOTHING;
```

get ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

---

Guessing that the problem is because foreign key.

can sql statement add "returning id"? I need to get note id.

Comment: can you add the create table statements too?   or dump the schema and attach

Comment: 1) A `FOREIGN KEY` is not a `UNIQUE` constraint. You will need to point the `ON CONFLICT` at the `id` field. or create a `UNIQUE` constraint say `UNIQUE(author_id, article_id)`(assuming that is possible. 2) Rather then read random Internet articles read the docs [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) in particular [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ｉwill try to  read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adrian Klaver for the suggestion, rebuilt after research table.

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    reader_id integer references users(id),
    article_id integer references articles(id),
    UNIQUE(reader_id, article_id)
)
```

Complete the original requirements, add return the last insert Id

```
INSERT INTO notes (article_id, reader_id)
    VALUES (1, 1)
    ON CONFLICT (article_id, reader_id) 
    DO Nothing
    RETURNING notes.id;
```